# ng-include loading partial partial only once

Tags: angularjs

Ng-include is driving me nuts and I really hope you can help. 
So I have this html code on the master page

`<div id="subViewPartial">
    <ng-include class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" src="currentPartial">
    </ng-include>
</div>`

and in angularjs I have the following functions

```
$scope.createUnit = function (link) {
        $rootScope.Action = 0;
        $rootScope.Id = 0;

        $scope.currentPartial = window.location.origin + link;
        setTimeout(SubViewService.showSubView(), 500);
    };

$scope.createUser = function (link) {
        //////console.log(link);
        $scope.currentPartial = window.location.origin + link;
        setTimeout(SubViewService.showSubView(), 500);
    };
```

Now, if fire createUser once, and then I execute createUnit serveral times, the subview will rotate between createUser and createUnit even though I am not calling createUser.

Here is the SubviewService as well

```
BAapp.service('SubViewService', function () {
this.showSubView = function () {
    var subViewContent = '#subViewPartial';

    $.subview({
        content: subViewContent,
        onShow: function () {
        },
        onClose: function () {
            $.hideSubview();
        },
        onHide: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

});

I hope that I am clear in explaining the problem. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What does $.subview() do? It looks like it's a jQuery plugin or something. Also, can you please provide some context on how this code is added to the DOM? I mean, what is the $scope.createUnit... code part of? A component? A controller? If so, how is that component/controller added to the page?

Comment: Hi Robba, yes subview is a jquery pluggin. $scope.CreateUnit as well as $scope.CreateUser are parts of different controllers and if they are invoked consequently, every call to '$scope.currentPartial = window.location.origin + link;' will rotate through once opened partials. BTW. $.subview() just displays the div content in an animated fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is take a good look at where the `createUnit()` and `createUser()` functions are called. For instance by setting `console.debug()` statements or a `debugger` statement in those methods.

You mention they are part of separate controllers, does this mean the functions are called during initialization of said controllers?

If this is the case, you are probably (accidentally) creating the controller that calls `createUser()` more than you think, possibly because of `ng-include`, `ng-if` or `ng-switch` constructions.

Comment: Robba, in the debugger both functions createUser and createUnit are fired upon call. But what I have noticed is that the partial view controller (MVC .NET) fires up only the first time the partial is loaded. It's as if ng-include stores the partial view in memory.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what MVC has to do with it, I assume you're generating the Angular views on the fly using MVC, but it is correct that Angular only downloads each template once as it stores it using the $templateCache service. Your problem seems to be with the createUser being called more than once am i right?

Comment: Yes Robba, all my views are linked to a specific action result in an MVC controller. The problem is that when I open two or more partial views (through ng-include) it will rotate between those views in cache. I.e step 1) click createUser => create user partial is loaded, step 2) click createUnit => create User Partial is loaded (herein lies the problem), step 3) click createUnit => create Unit partial is loaded, step 4) click createUnit => create User partial is loaded. Hope you see the problem. Is there a way to empty $templateCache service?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. $templateCache.removeAll();
seems to do the trick. Weird :{